# Bitcoind, what's the command to see available funds?

Tags: bitcoind

Bitcoind, what is the command to see how many btc is available combined in all wallets?

Comment: Related: [How to get an address's balance with the bitcoin client?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10090/5406)

Comment: It is not clear to me whether you are asking for the global unspent transaction outputs or the user's balance.

Answer (score 1):

`bitcoind getinfo`

The Bitcoin daemon supports just one wallet, not multiple.

Comment: Then what about wallet addresses. Aren't those wallets.

Comment: A wallet is not an address. An address is not a wallet. I answered the question you asked.