# Block number + bitcoin address -> Find transactions with bitcoind?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, bitcoind, api, block

If I have a block number and a bitcoin address -> Can I list all transactions for this address with an bitcoind command? Or mutliple commands?

Comment: Without using any programming language?

Answer (score 1):

some pseudo-code to work with the [Bitcoin-Core 0.16](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getrawtransaction) (if there are simpler ways pls lmk).

suppose you all have is `height` and `addr`

```
hash = getblockhash(height)
block = getblock(hash)

for txid in block[‘txid’]:

  tx = getrawtransaction(txid)

  for vi in tx['vin']:
    original_tx = getrawtransaction(vi['txid'])
    for vo in original_tx['vout']:
      if vo['n'] == vi['vout'] and addr in vo['scriptPubKey']['addresses']:
        print('this tx is relevant')

  for vo in tx['vout']:
    if addr in vo['scriptPubKey']['addresses']:
      print('this tx is relevant')
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [How to get an address's balance with the bitcoin client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10090/how-to-get-an-addresss-balance-with-the-bitcoin-client) which has an excellent answer.

Sorry to post as an answer since rep is too low :)