# Get balance and TXs

Tags: api, tokens, nft

How to get balances and transactions of a Bitcoin address? - Devsuite

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an address's balance with the bitcoin client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10090/how-to-get-an-addresss-balance-with-the-bitcoin-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to see the balance from your Bitcoin address, you can use QuickNode.

Here is an example:
https://www.quicknode.com/guides/quicknode-products/apis/look-up-the-address-balance-for-a-wallet-for-bitcoin-on-quicknode

Irwing Tello